# MEF Different Assembly Version Loading Issue

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have a bit of a conundrum with MEF.

I have an installer and configuration application shell which uses MEF to load individual installer components. This gives an end user the ability to select from whatever components have been placed into the install distributable.

The first install components which were written to use this used version 11 of SQLServer SMO libraries. Installing against either 2008R2 or 2012 works fine. (lets call this component A)

I have another team migrating code to a new component but that code uses version 10 of the SQLServer SMO, RMO, and SSIS (DTS) libraries. (lets call this component B)

When MEF goes to load component B I get a LoaderExceptionFailure for one of the SQLServer DLLs (Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication). It actually gives a FileNotFoundException (listing the DLL).  The DLL exists in the component's directory. It is the correct version 10.

The shell application already has version 11 files in it.

Is there a way I can tell the application context what to do?  Is there a way I can tell the component to load any specific libraries it needs?

I want to assume that each component can specify something "Associated.Library, Version=1.0.0.0, publickey=abcdef123456789, culture=none".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the CLR (not MEF) cannot find the assembly is because it is neither in the GAC, not in the places were the current AppDomain is setup to probe for assemblies.

One way to deal with this kind of problem is to add the missing assembly to the GAC.

Another approach is to add the folder containing the missing assembly to the probing paths of your application. If you don't mind deploying these assemblies in the application base folder (the one containing your executable) then do so. Otherwise you can add deploy it in a sub folder of your application base folder and add the folder to the [privatePath element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) of your **app.config**.

You will find more information on the article: [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I found the privatePath MSDN link. This helped with the libraries that were component specific. This still didn't solve the SQL Server 2008R2/2012 problem.  I ended up making those assemblies part of the core application and using this technique for probing: <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Server" publicKeyToken="c0305c36380ba429" /> 
         <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="v1/Server.dll"/>
         <codeBase version="2.0.0.0" href="v2/Server.dll"/>
   </dependentAssembly>